# My contact preferences in Lotus Notes 9.0.1FP4 look different from others in my company

Tags: lotus-notes

My Contact preferences in Lotus Notes look completely different from others. I do not have the ability to enable recent contacts, where others do. There is not a policy to disallow recent contacts at my company.

What could be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the design of your address book is still on a previous version. You could try replacing the design on it, but might want check with your helpdesk/note administrator first.